# Memoization yields slower results

Tags: python, dictionary, python-decorators, memoization

I am creating a memoization example with a function that adds up / averages the elements of an array and compares it with the cached ones to retrieve them in case they are already stored.

In addition, I want to store only if the result of the function differs considerably (passes a threshold e.g. 5000 below).

I created an example using a decorator to do so, the results using the decorator is slightly slower than without the memoization which is not OK, also is the logic of the decorator correct ?

My code is attached below:

```
import time

import random
from collections import OrderedDict

def memoize(f):
    cache = {}
    def g(*args):
        sum_key_arr = sum(args[0]) 
        print(sum_key_arr)
        if sum_key_arr not in cache:
            for key, value in OrderedDict(sorted(cache.items())).items():# key in dict cannot be an array so I use the sum of the array as the key
                if abs(sum_key_arr - key) <= 5000:#threshold is great here so that all values are approximated!
                    #print('approximated')
                    return cache[key]
            else:
                #print('not approximated')
                cache[sum_key_arr] = f(args[0],args[1])
        return cache[sum_key_arr]  
    return g
@memoize
def aggregate(dict_list_arr,operation):
    if operation == 'avg':
        return sum(dict_list_arr) / len(list(dict_list_arr)) 
    if operation == 'sum':
        return sum(dict_list_arr)
    return None
    
t = time.time()
for i in range(200,150000):
    res = aggregate(list(range(i)),'avg')
elapsed = time.time() - t
print(res)
print(elapsed)
```

UPDATE: I tried to involve an id key (that captues the list content) while now using a dict as input, here's below the changes made to the code:

```
import time
import random
from collections import OrderedDict

def memoize(f):
    cache = {}
    def g(*args):
        
        key_arr = list(args[0].keys())[0]
        if key_arr not in cache:
            for key, value in OrderedDict(sorted(cache.items())).items():# key in dict cannot be an array so I use the sum of the array as the key
                if abs(int(key_arr) - int(key)) <= 5000:#threshold is great here so that all values are approximated!
                    print('approximated')
                    return cache[key]
            else:
                print('not approximated')
                cache[key_arr] = f(args[0])
        return cache[key_arr]  
    return g
#@memoize
def aggregate(dict_list_arr):
     
    #if operation == 'avg':
    return sum(list(dict_list_arr.values())[0]) / len(list(dict_list_arr.values())[0]) 
    # if operation == 'sum':
        # return sum(dict_list_arr)
    # None
    
t = time.time()
for i in range(200,15000):
    res = aggregate({str(1+i):list(range(i))})
elapsed = time.time() - t
print(res)
print(elapsed)
```

Comment: You are sorting the items in the cache and doing a linear search every single time you don't have an item already in the cache. That is certainly going to make things slower! You need to find a better caching strategy. Ideally you want the lookup into cache to be as fast as possible. Currently, it is even slower than your original function.

Comment: well, any idea how to improve this without using the linear search?

Comment: For your use case it's not going to be very simple since you are interested in intervals. An [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) data structure might be what you are looking for. However, I would not expect a Python implementation to be very fast, so you would probably only see an improvement in performance for short input lists.

Comment: Also now that I notice: your current implementation is even more flawed than I originally thought. You are computing the result the same way the `aggregate` function does *before looking into the cache* and then use *the result itself* as a key. That does not make any sense whatsoever. This means that in case you have the item already cached you *still do the calculation*, and in the case it is not cached you do the calculation *two times*. A memoization decorator should *not* depend on the code of the underlying funciton, but in this case you copied the code as is inside the decorator.

Comment: Given that all your `aggregate` function does is essentially iterate over the input list once, there is no possible perfect caching strategy that wouldn't take more time than the original function, because the sole act of calculating whatever key you wanna use based on the input means scanning the input (which already takes as much as the original function). Other non-perfect strategies may be possible, e.g. looking only at the first few elements, or at the `id` of the input list, but other than that, there isn't really a way to memoize such a calculation.

Comment: could you explain the id based fetching

Comment: Just an example, if you get *exactly* the same list twice, using `id(input_list)` as key can help. That is not the case for the code you posted though as you are creating a new list every time.

Comment: but then how do you handle the approximation step? because of id is the key then sum of the list is not saved anymore

Comment: pls check my update involving an id